# Архитектурное решение для замены switch case

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Необходимо заменить swtich case условия. 
Симулятор фермы, который содержит несколько системных классов и классы, которые представляет животных. 
Все животные по категориям помещаются в списки (Sheeps, Pigs, etc). Оттуда их нужно вытаскивать от желания пользователя.

Рассматривается два варианта ввода команд

1. `pig kill` или `pig feed` и `exit`
2. `pigs` -> загружается сцена со статистикой -> `feed`;

Соответственно использовать switch-case условия очень неудобно. В первом варианте вообще нет не малейшей идеи, как оптимизировать реализацию.

Во втором варианте была идея использовать паттерн strategy со словарями, но это практически не решает поставленную задачу уменьшения кода.

Также в результате столкнулся с проблемой хранения текущих животных. Стоит ли создавать один большой объект, который хранит в себе списки животных или каким-то образом дробить на подклассы?

Answer (score 2):

Не вижу особенной проблемы.

У вас есть класс «животное» и подклассы «свинья»/«овца»? Или там тег конкретного вида, например, `enum AnimalKind`?

Вот и славно. Заведите класс `Inventory`, который будет знать всех животных. Сделайте у него метод `IEnumerable<Animal> GetAnimalsBySpecies(string species)`, которое по имени возвращать список животных. И пользуйтесь им везде.

Что внутри класса? Вариантов много. Например, вы можете держать отдельно списки животных каждого вида, и завести `Dictionary<string, List<Animal>>`, который будет отображать строку с именем на список. Или завести отображение строки на `AnimalKind`, и делать LINQ-запрос `AllAnimals.Where(a => a.Kind == kind)`. В принципе, не так уж важно, что именно внутри, главное, чтобы код снаружи видел чистый интерфейс.

Answer (score -2):

1. Тут без switch никак
2. Тоже
3. Я бы сделал классы CurentPigs, CurentSheep etc, где хранил списки этих животных