# Оператор switch вложенный в другой. Как сократить?

Tags: c#, switch, рефакторинг

Суть такова - есть динамическое кол-во игроков которое определяется юзером. Нам нужно сделать что бы при вызове метода менялся цвет игрока который сейчас будет ходить. Нельзя ли покороче и по-понятнее сделать метод ChangeColor?? Говорю спасибо на перед. 
P.S Оранжевый цвет ходящего.

```
void ChangeColor( )//Самый сложный и ужасный метод в моей жизни
    {
        switch (names.Count)
        {
            case 2:
                switch (counter)
                {
                    case 0:
                        label1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                        label2.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        label2.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                        label1.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                switch (counter)
                {
                    case 0:
                        label1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                        label2.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        label2.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                        label3.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        label3.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                        label1.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                switch (counter)
                {
                    case 0:
                        label1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                        label2.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        label2.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                        label3.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        label3.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                        label4.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        label4.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                        label1.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Метод который использует метод выше.

```
private void move_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Событие кнопки /ХОД/
{
    if (counter == names.Count)
    counter = 0;

    scores[counter] += CountScores ( );
    ChangeColor ( );
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Есть паттерны программирования для замены switch, но прежде чем говорить об этом -- расскажите, какой смысл вы вкладываете во все эти константы? Или вам просто сказать названия, а вы дальше сами разбрайтесь. И да, в поиске по сайту уже есть темы на замену switch - и поскольку у вас непонятно, что к чему - можно придубликатить практически к первой попавшейся.

Comment: Не понял? В паттернах я ещё не силён (вообще)

Comment: Искал по сайту даже на английских версиях и что-то не продуктивно.

Comment: Ну вот что под руку [подвернулось](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495799/213987): видите, у человека есть enum с осмысленными параметрами, у вас тоже можно позаменять незначащие цифры на  константы. И ещё меня смущает, что для каждого case у вас число вложенных вариантов совпадает с порядковым номером выбора: для двух - два, для трёх - три, для четырёх - четыре, внутри тоже видна структура, может быть это проще можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше бы вообще отказаться от оператора `switch`, полностью переделав метод.

Предлагаю закинуть объекты labelXXX в один массив или список, в порядке возрастания номера игрока, и можно будет сделать такой вот компактный код:

```
List<Label> player_labels = new List<Label>();

static void ChangeColor()
{
    int next_player_index = (counter + 1) % player_count;

    for (int i = 0; i < player_labels.Count; i++)
        player_labels[i].ForeColor = (i == next_player_index) ? Color.Orange : Color.Black;
}
```

Так и универсальности больше: если возникнет необходимость создавать игру на 5 или 6 игроков, то не потребуется вносить изменения в данный метод.

Comment: А вот не указал маленькую деталь - у меня всегда Label'ов 4 а ко нажатию кнопки я делаю их активными. Можно ли как-то убрать неактивные?

Comment: Сейчас появилась идея отпишусь как только буду готов

Comment: Да в общем-то похоже можно сделать: такой же цикл, и делаем неактивными метки у которых индекс в списке >= количества игроков.

Comment: роботает только немного не по задумке. Показвает цвет игрока который уже походил

Comment: Поправил ответ, теперь должно указывать на следующего. Только вместо `player_count` подставьте имя переменной, в которой сидит количество игроков

Comment: Отлично заработало! Надо запомнить прием с ? : Забыл как выражение называеться

Comment: "тернарный оператор", если не ошибаюсь

Comment: Да точно спасибо ещё раз!